# Turn off EKcalendar's Alerts

Tags: ios, calendar, notifications, eventkit

In the interface of the calendar on an iOS device, there is [this switch](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/tips/comments/turning-off-alerts-for-individual-calendars-in-ios-8), that turns off all alerts of that specific calendar. I would like to set that switch programmatically.

Does any of you know a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Oh, you completely changed you question... i remove my answer

Comment: Well, yes, I made it a bit shorter and more comprehensible. Apologies for the inconvenience.